# PDF not downloading in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a project that should be printing a PDF file. But whenever I press the **Print Receipt** button, it doesn't download anything. What is the issue?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView mywebview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings=mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.loadUrl("Some URL");

    mywebview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    //Code for Opening the app
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}

//Code for Back button


}
```

Comment: Did you added storage permission?

Comment: Im not sure, but i put this in the manifest
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>